# Firebase: Difference between Firebase InstallationID and fcmToken

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is [InstallationID](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseinstallations/api/reference/Classes/Installations#/c:objc(cs)FIRInstallations(im)installationIDWithCompletion:) and fcmToken or [token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasemessaging/api/reference/Classes/Messaging#/c:objc(cs)FIRMessaging(im)tokenWithCompletion:) different or the same in Firebase. If they are different then how?

It is not clearly explained in the [migration guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/manage-installations#swift_11) how they are different. It does mention though that how ***InstanceID*** is different from ***InstallationsID***

It is mentioned in their docs about the token that

> This creates a Firebase Installations ID, if one does not exist, and sends information about the application and the device to the Firebase backend. A network connection is required for the method to succeed.

This is even more confusing if someone is using the [token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasemessaging/api/reference/Classes/Messaging#/c:objc(cs)FIRMessaging(im)tokenWithCompletion:) API to register the token and then [migration guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/manage-installations#swift_11) say we have to replace it [with](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/manage-installations#retrieving-an-identifier)

```
Installations.installations().installationID { (id, error) in
  if let error = error {
    print("Error fetching id: \(error)")
    return
  }
  guard let id = id else { return }
  print("Installation ID: \(id)")
}
```

Comment: These are indeed all different values/concepts, but typically you'd use them in the same/quite similar ways in your apps. Can you explain what you're trying to accomplish, and why you think the difference matters?

Comment: added the reason why I would like to know the actual difference without going through its source code.

Comment: Thanks for that update . I'm still not sure what the problem is though. Are you have a problem with the new code for getting the Installation ID?

Comment: I am trying to use the installationIDs instead of instanceIDs and I am not sure that the token should be retrieved/registered with Messaging.messaging().token or Installations.installations().installationID?

Comment: As far as I can tell from https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#fetching-the-current-registration-token, you should use `Messaging.messaging().token`, which is supposed to hide whatever the token is from your application code (as far as I understand). Is that not working for you?

Comment: It is working for me. But thinking of it as a perspective to delete user data, installationID would be needed as it is explained here. `When you delete an installation ID, the data tied to that installation ID is removed from live and backup systems of all Firebase services that use Firebase installation IDs to identify installations within 180 days`.  If fcmToken or token is used that can't be done. Please correct me If I am wrong?

Comment: the tokens aren't automatically removed from your database ( it is required to store them) , but it will report errors if you try to use them which allows you to delete them or enact certain behaviours, such as send the user an email saying "we miss you" - etc

Comment: When we delete the installation ID either from client or from the server wouldn't that also delete all kind of tokens associated with the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize, the installation ID is used within the device and as a self-reference so the app is able to distinguish itself from others. as multiple apps could be using firebase as their main app driver.

The FCM token is a token generated for the device, also used to identify the device in question but is used to identify the device in the notification network rather than internally amongst other apps.

Both are used in similar ways to identify the device and the app but are ultimately for different purposes. If you are dealing with Firebase Messaging, you will need to reference the FCM token.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please comment on the last comment above? :)